# Problem scraping Amazon using requests: I get blocked even when using cookie and headers. I can only scrape using a browser. Any solution?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

The requests module isn't working anymore for me when trying to scrape amazon, I've tried using cookies, headers, changing IP's but nothing really works other than scraping through a browser. Does anyone know how they're able to do it and if there's a good work around using requests?

The real odd thing is that the request when sent through cURL returns the page, but if I turn it into python code it returns a captcha request that I can't see in my browser and doesn't go away even with cookies.

For example this cURL request returns the Amazon main page, but when truend into python it returns a captcha request:

```
curl -L -vvv http://amazon.com -H "User-Agent:Mozilla 5.0"
```

This is my current code, I copied the curl request directly from the browser and turned into python code, still not working:

import requests

```
cookies = {
    'session-id': '135-4585428-6195300',
    'session-id-time': '2082787201l',
    'i18n-prefs': 'USD',
    'sp-cdn': '"L5Z9:IL"',
    'ubid-main': '132-1503580-7678418',
    'session-token': 'R5XVE3t8VeX8bRwnjuxXwONDgBnxkngfLfzobFxK5HL+8QaofrVEPjv8Mvta3D6EMlaiFeOyhjjiHkHLjjRwlh9seQ0wsfXE0BU0csh2Wtx6q6r630bsx5VvbBIQcyVAPRkgvL5wgU12P39t5iCZ7b3ykFjRvb9qe7eScZC/F9DJ+NuFMOVP+Z7OQtlZNQzcYrKmWTJH0HJZho8VtJBish0ATwfLhVI+Ihu1ioHYUfSUNDdjQFgG7SyiKZDufkXekZZGaF3x24vY9haBeJVnE9GjmMN+XHySuQtP/stlZmhlp9JOH17+JTZHVsCn/SEONdK5QhETXzoaQ+9YvptxA+v49bgXJn+L',
    'csm-hit': 'tb:NBK78382HSSRXD9W22YX+s-SKXXAE4EMPQ2XYNGK1G0|1692968547644&t:1692968547644&adb:adblk_no',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.amazon.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    # 'cookie': 'session-id=135-4585428-6195300; session-id-time=2082787201l; i18n-prefs=USD; sp-cdn="L5Z9:IL"; ubid-main=132-1503580-7678418; session-token=R5XVE3t8VeX8bRwnjuxXwONDgBnxkngfLfzobFxK5HL+8QaofrVEPjv8Mvta3D6EMlaiFeOyhjjiHkHLjjRwlh9seQ0wsfXE0BU0csh2Wtx6q6r630bsx5VvbBIQcyVAPRkgvL5wgU12P39t5iCZ7b3ykFjRvb9qe7eScZC/F9DJ+NuFMOVP+Z7OQtlZNQzcYrKmWTJH0HJZho8VtJBish0ATwfLhVI+Ihu1ioHYUfSUNDdjQFgG7SyiKZDufkXekZZGaF3x24vY9haBeJVnE9GjmMN+XHySuQtP/stlZmhlp9JOH17+JTZHVsCn/SEONdK5QhETXzoaQ+9YvptxA+v49bgXJn+L; csm-hit=tb:NBK78382HSSRXD9W22YX+s-SKXXAE4EMPQ2XYNGK1G0|1692968547644&t:1692968547644&adb:adblk_no',
    'device-memory': '8',
    'downlink': '10',
    'dpr': '1',
    'ect': '4g',
    'rtt': '100',
    'sec-ch-device-memory': '8',
    'sec-ch-dpr': '1',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Microsoft Edge";v="116"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform-version': '"10.0.0"',
    'sec-ch-viewport-width': '1037',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.54',
    'viewport-width': '1037',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B002G9UDYG', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can scrape Amazon with `Python Requests` even if you try to use information extract from a valid browser session.

**basic curl connection**

> curl -I http://www.amazon.com

The response below shows that the URL is using `Amazon CloudFront` and has a status code of 301, which tell us that the URL is being permanently redirect to some other URL

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: CloudFront
Date: Wed, 30 Aug 2023 12:41:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 167
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.amazon.com/
X-Cache: Redirect from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 322b7a8ce3aa88236c8ca9410d0b9300.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: ATL58-P3
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
X-Amz-Cf-Id: oK3dFCUCiQ6ZdAe_BEC5p-XbRxcrXFiYupSaYQOh6W1JS85BJsLrKA==
```

**Python Requests**

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/')

print(response.status_code)
503 

print(response.headers)
{'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'Server', 'Date': 'Wed, 30 Aug 2023 12:52:08 GMT', 'x-amz-rid': 'YXG2PT1GB1T7GY4Q19KC', 'Vary': 'Content-Type,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent', 'Last-Modified': 'Mon, 12 Jun 2023 22:17:25 GMT', 'ETag': '"a6f-5fdf615518740-gzip"', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=47474747; includeSubDomains; preload', 'X-Cache': 'Error from cloudfront', 'Via': '1.1 71cf657de17d1d4de9dbcb4ff38d54c0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Pop': 'ATL56-P1', 'Alt-Svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'Rxe_ROuUee2QLLxW7e8tVqbJ4WwRK3JXbhjxrgV-WXwrb0q6pdzdbg=='}
```

*The status code 503 indicates that the server is temporarily unable to handle the request. The headers show that `Amazon CloudFront` is not allowing the connection.*

If we exam the content of the page (response.text) you will see this:

> To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com. For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref=rm_5_sv

Based on the information Amazon is trying to prevent someone from scraping their site with tools, such as `Python Requests`.  I would recommend trying `selenium` or Amazon's API.

Here are some sites that highlight how to use `selenium` to scrape Amazon:

- [Web Scraping on Amazon with Selenium](https://www.kaggle.com/code/jesusacunamorillo/web-scraping-on-amazon-with-selenium-python)
- [Web Scraping with Selenium in Python — Amazon Search Result](https://medium.com/@jb.ranchana/web-scraping-with-selenium-in-python-amazon-search-result-part-1-f09c88090932)
- [Amazon Products Web Scraping Using Selenium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0DnDq5yRVs)

Comment: Would there be any advantage of using selenium in headless mode as opposed to just running curl requests from python using subprocess?  It looks like subprocess is faster.

Comment: I think your `curl requests` will likely get blocked before `selenium` in headless mode would.

Comment: Scraping Amazon solely with requests is still possible by specifying "session-id" and "Cookie" headers, the latter was what OP was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Python Code
Its pretty simple,

```
headers = {
'User-Agent': '',
}

request = requests.get(url='https://amazon.com', headers=headers)
print(request)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).